# "arara" shows "java" error: "\runscript.tlu:921: command failed with exit code 1: java.exe -jar"

Tags: arara, java

When I run `arara` for a LaTeX file, the error is here:

> C:\texlive\2023\bin\windows\runscript.tlu:921: command failed with
> exit code 1: java.exe -jar
> c:\texlive\2023\texmf-dist\scripts\arara\arara.jar whu-thesis-demo.tex

Rarely `arara` works normally, but most of the time it doesn't. I guess it is caused by `arara` not `java`, as my `java` version is

> java version "1.8.0_371" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
> 1.8.0_371-b11) Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.371-b11, mixed mode, sharing)

I am using Window 11, and I run `arara filename.tex` on terminal(Window Powershell).  The editor is VScode. At the beginning of the file, there is:

```
% arara: clean: { extensions: [ aux, log, pdf, bcf, blg, mw, out, xml, toc, glo, hd, idx, gz] }
% arara: xelatex
% arara: biber
% arara: xelatex
% arara: xelatex
```

How to fix this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Which text editor are you using, TeX Works? How have you set `arara` up, could you include more information please. Can see you are using TeX Live 23 on Windows but how you are attempting to use `arara` is needed

Comment: @JamesT Thanks. I have updated my question.

Comment: Do the compilations complete without error if you execute them manually? Does `arara` consistently fail for a basic document like `% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Foo
\end{document}`

Comment: @DaiBowen After rebooting the PC, the `arara` works right now. So, I can't reproduce this problem. But it sometime has this error, so when next time I meet this again, I will do the check you suggested.

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness: as detailed in the arara manual, arara would fail with exit code 2 if it is an exception in arara code. It only fails with exit code 1 if one of the rules fails. So next time you meet this again, make sure to also check the log that it is not actually one of the clean/xelatex/biber runs that actually fails and whose failure just propagates.